# Dropbox Python SDK v2: sharing_list_shared_links(...) repeatedly returns the same cursor

Tags: python, sdk, dropbox

When I call

*sharing_list_shared_links(path=None, cursor=None, direct_only=None)*

using the official Python SDK v2 the resulting *ListSharedLinksResult* contains the same cursor, which leads to an endless loop in the worst case (see code snippet).
The *has_more* flag is true in every iteration.

```
cursor = None
while True:
    result = api.sharing_list_shared_links(cursor=cursor)

    for link in result.links:
        store_link(link)

     if not result.has_more:
        break
     cursor = result.cursor
```

We are using the account for continuous integration tests, which means that the account may somehow be broken.

Did anyone else experience the same behaviour?

Greets,
  Hannes

Comment: What should the *official Python SDK v2* be? and please share some more, runnable code with us.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206026743-sharing-list-shared-links-repeatedly-returns-the-same-cursor- ]

Comment: Thank you Greg. This post was posted by myself.